# Multiple Selecting Item in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

Using the code from this page to start with:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/DragginganddroppingbetweenListView.htm

I am trying to find out what needs to be added to support two more features:
a) Be able to multi-select and move items all together.
b) Be able to do the moving on a single item when we double click on it.

Any more information, reading material, to help with two questions above that can put me on the right track are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there something unclear about my answer? Ask questions in the answer's comments, if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `MultiSelect = True` in the designer. This allows you to select > 1 items.

I'm not sure what you mean *"Be able to do the moving on a single item when we double click on it"*. It sounds like you want to move an item from one `ListView` to another when you double-click it. In that case, create a copy of the `ListViewItem` you double-clicked in the double-click event (I think it's e.Item, maybe?) and then add it or insert it into the other list in the code-behind. If you want to delete it from the list you double-clicked on, just use `MyListView.RemoveAt` and pass the index of that item.

This isn't too bad to write, code-wise, so I won't write out all the steps. But that's what you'll want to do, step-wise.